# Calculate the average when i filter by groups

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10

i have a problem when i've tried to show the average of a field in the tree view.

> percentage = fields.Float(string='Porcentaje', compute='fill_percentage', store=True,default=False)

```
  @api.model
  def read_group(self, domain, fields, groupby, offset=0, limit=None, orderby=False, lazy=True):
    res = super(Project_Task_Extension, self).read_group(domain, fields, groupby, offset=offset,
                                                         limit=limit, orderby=orderby, lazy=lazy)

    if 'percentage' in fields:
        for line in res:
            if '__domain' in line:
                value = 0.0
                aux = 0
                lines = self.search(line['__domain'])
                for x in lines:
                    value += x.percentage
                    aux += 1
                total = value/aux
                line['percentage'] = total
    return res

    ----in the xml----
    <field name="percentage" avg="Average"/>
```

with this code works perfectly but when I tried to filter for example by 'project', the final average is not correct, any suggestions?

[In this image the average is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCOYB.png)

[but with this filter the total average is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRqLe.png)

in second the image, the total should be (85.71 + 100 +0)/3=61.90...

Comment: Can you give us an example of the calculations

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I've updated my post

Comment: Where does your function apply a filter?

Comment: hi, in my  function i dont do it . 
I mean when I apply the filter in the same view. Also, I've tried adding it with a conditional : if  'project' in 'groupby': but as the same result.